# Returning value from Action Performed for use in other class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, interface

i have the following code for creating a drop down menu that contains certain ranks ,
i need to be able to get whatever rank the user has selected from the menu so i can use the answer in other classes

```
package userInterface;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    String[] messageStrings = { "RANK 1", "RANK 2", "RANK 3" };

    JComboBox cmbMessageList = new JComboBox(messageStrings);
    JLabel user = new JLabel();
    JLabel item1;
    String user_rank;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        gui newguiGui = new gui();

        newguiGui.setVisible(true);

    }

    public gui() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        cmbMessageList.setSelectedIndex(1);
        cmbMessageList.addActionListener(this);
        add(cmbMessageList);
        add(user);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        item1 = new JLabel("enter the street you are on here");

        item1.setToolTipText("In this box you enter if you are: pre flop, flop, turn or river");

        // adding items to the interface

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getSource() == cmbMessageList) {
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            String msg = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
            switch (msg) {
            case "RANK 1":
                user_rank = "RANK 1";
                break;
            case "RANK 2":
                user_rank = "RANK 2";
                break;
            case "RANK 3":
                user_rank = "RANK 3";
                break;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your `String user_rank` public if your other class is not in the same package:

```
public String user_rank;
```

Then you can access it with `gui.user_rank`.

Also:

- Use `userRank` instead to follow Java naming conventions.
- Use `Gui` for class name for same reason as above.
- **Immediately** replace `e.getSource() == cmbMessageList` with `e.getSource().equals(cmbMessageList)`.
- You don't need to call `setLayout(new FlowLayout())` 3 times.

Another approach would be to add a (public or default access) method which would return `user_rank` and have the other class call that method. In this case you can make your variable even `private`.

Comment: perfect thank you for the great reply, and oops i didn't notice the flow layout thing before i pasted it in, must have been from before haha, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably store it in a variable. And use it by calling a getter method.